# How to solve ENOENT error of 'next build' command?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, build

I am trying to build my NextJS application with next build command. I am using getStaticProps and getStaticPaths to fetch data from an API and multi-language is also enabled.

Here is the error message:

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/Users/.../build/export/tr/success-story.html' -> '/Users/.../build/server/pages/tr/success-story.html'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'rename',
  path: '/Users/.../build/export/tr/success-story.html',
  dest: '/Users/.../build/server/pages/tr/success-story.html'
}
```